# Why does > 3,2,1 evaluate to 1 in Javascript

Tags: javascript, syntax

I observed the following behaviour in both Firefox Console and Node and can't think of an explanation. Can you explain why this happens? I actually expected a syntax error. Same behaviour occurs with strings or arrays.

```
> 3,2,1
1

> "abc", "bca", "cba"
'cba'

> [1], [2], [3]
[ 3 ]
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Comment: Thanks, I totally missed that one and the duplicate question.